# Синоним "Добавить папку" (Add directory)

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Существует ли синоним к "Добавить папку" с меньшим количеством символов?

Comment: "Новая папка" подойдёт?

Comment: Хотя, этому соответствует New folder - видимо, здесь по смыслу нужно "Выбор папки" (из существующих)?

Comment: Да, имеется в виду из существующих.

Comment: Можно и в одно слово: "выбрать" или "путь", но это будет менее информативно, поскольку этим можно указать как на папку, так и на файл.

Comment: Alex_ander, А кто сказал, что в этом меню вообще ***файлы*** выбираются?

Answer (score 1):

Нормального синонима короткого нет. Нужен какой-то "иероглиф". 
А если без "**папка**" вообще? Или там "**+папка**"?

И неужели так критично по размеру?

Answer (score -1):

Ещё папка. Коряво немного. Создать — короче на один знак.

Comment: Имеется в виду  загрузить содержимое существующей папки в программу. "Еще папка" как-то не по-русски звучит.